# Class exam + marginnote: How to explain this indent problem?

Tags: indentation, exam, marginnote

I use the class exam and I want to use the marginnote package to put notes in the margin of some questions. When I use the last optional argument to change the vertical offset, it adds some indent at the beginning of the question. In the following MWE, the space is quite small, but in my real config, it is for some reason much bigger.

Where does this indent come from? How to prevent it (manual negative hspace for each note is not an option for me)?

NB: I don't care about the mess with vertical spaces in the margin. This is just to show that only the combination question + marginnote with voffset causes this effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \lipsum[2][3]
    
    \marginnote{Very first note} \lipsum[123][2]
    
    \marginnote{Try}[0pt] \lipsum[1][3]
    
    \marginpar{\vspace{1em}Other try} \lipsum[34][1]
\begin{questions}
    %\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{\raggedleft}
    \question \lipsum[1][5]
    \question \marginnote{First note} \lipsum[86][3]
    \question \marginnote{Some note}[0pt] \lipsum[2][1]% <--Causes unwanted indent
    \question \marginpar{\vspace{1em}Last note} \lipsum[34][1]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks John, but I'm using points.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. I change neither `\textwidth` nor `\marginparwidth` in my MWE. And the only reason I wrote the `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` line is to make more evident the fact that there is no indent problem outside of the questions environment : commenting it out doesn't solve the problem. But maybe there is something I don't understand in your comment.

Comment: I don't know, I feel we are not talking about the same issue. I compiled my MWE with pdflatex / xelatex and lualatex and got the same result every time. What I call indentation is the space between the question number and the first letter of the question. Are you talking about the same thing ?

Comment: Ah, that indentation.  You can get rid of it by deleting the space after `\marginnote{Some note}[0pt]`.  Probably a bug in `\marginnote` (missing `\ignorespaces`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you want to make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: Only if I get to fix \marginparwidth as well ;-)